# How to delay the launch of an mp3 file using vlc

Tags: python-3.x, vlc, speech-synthesis

```
from gtts import *
import os
import vlc
def sauvegarde(text,i):
    tts = gTTS(text, lang='fr')
    tts.save("text"+str(i)+".mp3")
def play(file):
    p = vlc.MediaPlayer(file)
    p.play()
text = "Salut Santo c\'est Alexis, ton maitre qui te parle"
text2="Bonjour Santo"
sauvegarde(text,1)
sauvegarde(text2,2)
play("text1.mp3")
play("text2.mp3")

os.system("pause")
```

When I run this code the two .mp3 files that I created previously are being played at the same time. Any ideas how to play the second one after the first is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vlc doesn't seem to have a blocking version of play as far as I can tell, so probably the easiest way to accomplish this is to manually wait for the first mp3 to finish. So to make a blocking version of your play function, try something like this:

```
import time
def play(file):
    p = vlc.MediaPlayer(file)
    p.play()
    while(p.is_playing()):
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

This will check is `p` is still playing every 100ms. Only when it is done playing, the play function will return.

Alternatively, you can use `vlc.MediaListPlayer` and `vlc.MediaList` to create a playlist containing your mp3's.